# how to get event scroll to bottom using iscroll library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

Need to  get an event when user scroll to bottom using iscroll library ?

I need a alert when user scroll to top and bottom. How can i do this ?

Here is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/13/

Here is my code :

```
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loaded();
  //  alert("--")

});
```

Answer (score 7):

Just add another option to the `iScroll` options like so:

```
var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
    bounce: true,
    onScrollEnd: function(e) {
        if (this.y == this.minScrollY)
            alert('This is the beginning');
        if (this.y == this.maxScrollY)
            alert('This is the end');
    } 
});
```

I've used the `onScrollEnd` event here but you can choose from multiple like <kbd>[these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957013/iscroll4-how-to-call-functions-when-the-div-is-scrolling/16958639#16958639)</kbd>.

You can find the working jsFiddle <kbd>[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7qaYP/)</kbd>.

### Update

### <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a9un6/)**</kbd>

To show you exactly what is possible, you could do for example the following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="begin"><b>The START</b></div>
<div id="end"><b>The END</b></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#begin {     
    height:80px;
    padding: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
}

#end {     
    height:80px;
    padding: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    display:none; 
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loaded() {  
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
        bounce: true,
        onScrollEnd: function(e) {
            if (this.y == this.minScrollY)
                $("#begin").show();
            if (this.y < this.minScrollY)
                $("#begin").hide();
            if (this.y == this.maxScrollY)
                $("#end").show();
            if (this.y > this.maxScrollY)
                $("#end").hide();
        } 
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loaded();    
});
```

Where you make a `div` appear at the beginning and the end.

You can find a demo of this implementation <kbd>[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/a9un6/)</kbd>

### Update: iScroll5

For iScroll 5 you do the following:

```
var myScroll;

function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { 
        scrollbars: true, 
        interactiveScrollbars: true,
        mouseWheel: true,
        fadeScrollbars: false 
    });
    myScroll.on('scrollEnd', function() {
            if (this.y == 0)
                $("#begin").show();
            if (this.y < 0)
                $("#begin").hide();
            if (this.y == this.maxScrollY)
                $("#end").show();
            if (this.y > this.maxScrollY)
                $("#end").hide();
        });
}

loaded();
```

and you also make sure you adhere to the new syntax and CSS specifications.

You can find some of these [HERE](http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/32-Updating-to-iScroll-5.html).

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nc276/)

or you can define a margin (maybe this works for magic mouse)

## [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Kjuq2/)

Comment: I need that exact function to iScroll5! Please how can I write that detecting(bottom and top) functions with it? ;O

Comment: No, your demo is for iScroll4.

Comment: @Strobel: And you can't make the modification yourself?

Comment: I'm close, the problem is the functions are firing multiple times when I reach top or bottom using the mousewheel of the apple magic mouse or trackpad.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I even tryed your demo on fiddle and it's not working with the mousewheel yet. :(

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/issues/397 and check my new demo 2, maybe it works because of continuously fired events.

Comment: The same on demo 2, events still firing repeatedly during the inertia. I think it's an issue with iScroll5. If there's a way to stop it after fire the first time. Do you have a magic mouse or trackpad? If you check on the console log you will understand better I guess.

Comment: Thank you very much for trying. I'm digging here even deeper and I found out it's not a simple issue as I thought. I'll keep trying and if I come up with the solution I'll tell you.

Comment: I can't accept because the original question isn't mine. But I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Strobel: Oh haha, I thought you were the original poster ;)

Comment: @Strobel did you ever find an answer to this problem? I'd love to know as I have it too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this library?

I prefer this one: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

But If it is a requirement, you must use the version 5.
Because the version 4 doesn't have the events.

If you can use the versione 5 at the end of this page https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll you can see how to configure the event.
For example:

```
myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper');
myScroll.on('scrollEnd', doSomething);
```

Comment: how can i use this library?

Comment: I just created a new version of your fiddler with the correct script, but this iScroll is not a good library, it is full of bugs. Here the url http://jsfiddle.net/cQ75J/16/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without using any third party library, as follows :

```
var closeToBottom = ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-550);
    if (closeToBottom) {
              //Do your stuff here
    }
```

You can change the position by modifying the number"550" which I has specified as default

Comment: You need to use a library like iScroll to make parts of a page i.e. div containers scrolling on iPad and maybe other tablets. iScroll uses hardware accerated transformations (CSS3) to move the div layer, so the normal scrolling properties like scrollTop are not available.